# In jquery when .last() is used, why does a different part of the function stop working?

Tags: jquery, row, selector, userscripts

How can I do both - Delete rows starting from the last row, and be able to add rows after deleting them?  My problem is that when I remove .last() from the code, it deletes starting from the first row instead of the last.  But if I add .last(), I can't add any rows after deleting rows.  Here is a link to the page with both the page source and frame source code.  It's really long and I'm not sure how much to add here.  https://www.mturk.com/mturk/preview?groupId=330XZFCZ7R28BGIGI0U62D26WPATXS

```
    $( document ).ready(function() {
       $("#receipt_date").focus();
       window.scrollTo(x-coord, y-coord);
    });

    $(document).keydown(function(f) {
      if(f.which == 219) {
         f.preventDefault();
         //clicks an href link by its id
         $('#add_item')[0].click();   
      }
      else if (f.which==221){
         f.preventDefault();
         //clicks an href link by its class
         $('a[class="delete_row"]').last()[0].click();
      } 
      else if(f.which == 13) {
         f.preventDefault();
         //clicks a submit button not an href link
         $('input[id="submit_button"]').trigger('click');
      }
  });
```

Comment: Note: `first()` on `$('#add_item').first()` is a waste of time as IDs must be unique and jQuery can only see the first match (should you have duplicates). Use classes instead.

Comment: Please show an example of your HTML too, so that a working mockup can be produced :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't my user script for Chrome/Tampermonkey add new rows, after adding and deleting rows?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28810138/why-wont-my-user-script-for-chrome-tampermonkey-add-new-rows-after-adding-and)

Answer (score 0):

`first()` on `$('#add_item').first()` is a waste of time as IDs must be unique and jQuery can only see the first match (should you have duplicates).

Until I see the HTML this is a guess, but if you do not have any element with class `add_item` then `[0]` in the following code will return undefined, so the following `click()` will crash, stopping all subsequent JavaScript on the page from running:

Change this:

```
 $('#add_item').first()[0].click();
```

to this:

```
 $('#add_item').click();
```

The second, jQuery, version will fail silently if the element does not match/exist.

Comment: the add item part works fine before deleting rows.  It also works after deleting rows if .last() is removed.  It only stops working if .last() is in the delete row part of the code.  I removed .first() and tried it again and it isn't working still.

Comment: @noThanks: The `add` seems to work fine, even after deletes, but the delete on the existing two items does not appear to work.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm using Google Chrome browser?  I had to change keypress to keydown for Chrome.  I'm using a newer desktop PC with Windows 8 or 8.1.  I keep googling things and I can't figure out this problem.

Comment: I am using Chrome too.

Comment: I have the user script in tamper monkey.  It won't let me add rows with the script and keyboard, after deleting rows.  Also I can't add more items by clicking the add items link with the mouse.  That only happens after deleting rows with the script.